# Open new terminal while main script still runs

Tags: perl, terminal, system, gnome

I need to open a **new terminal while the main script is still runing**. When testing the commands in command line everything is OK, but when running the perl script my new terminal windows are opened and closed in less than a second.

First new terminal window to be opened:

```
system ('gnome-terminal', '-x', 'sh', '-c', '"sslstrip -a -k -l 8080 -w sslstrip.log"');
```

Second new terminal window to be opened:

```
system ('gnome-terminal', '-x', 'sh', '-c', '"tail -f sslstrip.log"');
```

As I said the windows are opened and closed very quickly. I need them to stay opened while the script still runs.

I have already tried something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

use strict;
use warnings;

$| =1;

open STDOUT, '>-';
system("du /usr/lib/perl5 &");
close STDOUT;

open STDOUT, '>-';
system("xterm -e du /usr/lib/perl5 &");
close STDOUT;
```

But still isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out the doublequotes:

```
system ('gnome-terminal', '-x', 'sh', '-c', 'sslstrip -a -k -l 8080 -w sslstrip.log');
```

The doublequotes caused the entire line to be treated as the name of the command, rather than a command followed by arguments.

However, you'll need to fork a child process and run this in there, since this runs in the foreground and `system()` won't return until `gnome-terminal` exits. You can't use `&` with the multi-argument `system()` syntax, because it doesn't run a shell, so shell metacharacters don't work.

Comment: It worked for these lines. But now I'm facing the same problem with system ('gnome-terminal', '-x', 'sh', '-c', 'arpspoof -i $interface -t $target $gateway');. Is there another solution than forking a child process?